# filenamestr was not declared in this scope - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function to get file size. I tried using GetFileSizeEx but I couldn't get results that I wanted (I want it to be an integer or double) and to compare if it's larger than 1MB or not. Anyways, I made this function but I am getting an error that filenamestr is not declared.

```
    int getsize(std::string const $filename);
...    
    int getsize(std::string const $filenamestr)
        {
            std::fstream file(filenamestr);
            file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
            return file.tellg();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the `$` come from?

Comment: @KonradRudolph it must be some sort of cQuery

Comment: ahh damn just noticed it lol. thanks

Comment: I guess some compilers will recognize `$` as part of a variable name... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you do not preface a variable name with a dollar sign. Removing it should fix your problem:

```
    int getsize(std::string const filename);
...    
    int getsize(std::string const filenamestr)
        {
            std::fstream file(filenamestr);
            file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
            return file.tellg();
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I made a typo and spent the last 30 minutes looking for an answer without noticing it... :/ Got used to PHP

Also, I've got another question when this one is resolved anyways, when do I use the "&" sign infront of the string in a function?

Comment: The `&` has the same meaning it does in PHP - it means "pass by reference" instead of "pass by value." Normally, when you pass a parameter to a function, the function receives a *copy* of the parameter. An `&` changes your function makes to its parameters (for example, if you set `filenamestr=""` inside the function) last only for the duration of the function. Once the function returns, the changes are gone. Using an & means that the function operates on the same copy of the parameter as was passed into it, so any changes the function makes persist even after the function is finished.

Comment: _"Once the function returns, the variable reverts to its original state."_ This is a terrible way to explain it. The function parameter is a different variable, the original one is not altered, and does not need to revert because it never changed.

Comment: I know, I was trying to put it in a way that I figured a beginner would understand. But I'll edit my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I know that you're from PHP, I can see where the confusion is coming from. :)

Parameter names do not need to be prepended with a `$`. The name itself will just do. When you reference `filenamestr`, it looks for a variable with that exact identifier. But it doesn't see it because `$` is also a valid character for an identifier, and it makes `$filenamestr` a completely different variable in terms of its name.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign $ should not be used in variable names.  It is not supported by the C++ standard, although Visual C++ supports it.  It's best to remove it from your parameters, but the error is a result of the difference in `filenamestr` and `$filenamestr`, two different identifiers.

This will fix it.

```
int getsize(std::string const filename);
...    
int getsize(std::string const filenamestr)
    {
        std::fstream file(filenamestr);
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        return file.tellg();
    }
```