# What are the '@' and '$' for in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

So far, in MinGW, the '$' seems to be just a basic character (like 'a'), that can be used in names (variables, functions, etc.) But it doesn't look like one. Is there some hidden feature of using '$' as part of a name that I'm missing?

```
int $m = 2;
printf("$m = %i", $m);
```

Console Output:

```
$m = 2
```

However the '@' symbol produces an error when used as a character. `error: stray '@' in program` I assume that mean's that it's used for something? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++), and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x04xhy0h.aspx) don't mention either character. And Google gives plenty of matches for "symbol" or "C".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name

Comment: @ is typically for some meta purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `$` or `@` are part of standard C's character set (C11 **5.2.1 Character sets**, paragraph 3):

> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members: the 26 *uppercase letters* of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
>     A B C D E F G H I J K L M
>     N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> the 26 *lowercase letters* of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
>     a b c d e f g h i j k l m
>     n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> ```
>
> the 10 decimal *digits*
>
> ```
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> ```
>     ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
>     ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ {  | } ~
> ```
>
> the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.

The C++ standard says about the same (**2.2 Character sets**, paragraph 1):

> The *basic source character set* consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ∼ ! = , \ " ’
> ```

So if you can or can't use them (at all or even for a specific purpose) it's up to your implementation.

In your case it sounds like you're probably using GCC, which allows `$` in identifiers as an extension, but doesn't allow `@` - probably because GCC also compiles Objective-C code, where `@` has special meaning.

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html):

> In GNU C, you may normally use dollar signs in identifier names. This is because many traditional C implementations allow such identifiers. However, dollar signs in identifiers are not supported on a few target machines, typically because the target assembler does not allow them.