# Is there any problem to use characters `$` or `@` in C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if it is considered bad practice to use the characters `$` or `@` in C++ code where it is possible, like in macros.

I haven't seen those anywhere, even if they are in the ASCII table, just like 
`#` character for example.

I'm actually very tempted to name my macros like this "$SomeMacro()" instead of the good old screaming "SOME_MACRO()", it compiles fine in gcc, clang and msvc.

Comment: Use them for what? Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: If you mean using them in variable names, then no you cannot. Variables can only use underscores, letters, and numbers.

Comment: if you change "is it bad practice" to "is it allowed" it can make a nice question. The thing is what is bad practice is opinion-based and questions that are primarily opinion-based are considered offtopic at SO

Comment: Sorry my question missed a detail, it was mean to be used in macros, I'll edit this

Comment: for the opinion-based part: Yes it is bad practice. Variable names should be readable and pronouncable. If your variable has a `$` in it you make it more difficult to talk about it with your collegues for no gain

Comment: offtopic: better not use macros in the first place. In modern c++ there is only very few things you cannot do without macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea by any means, but if you come from the world of JavaScript (e.g. the famous jQuery's `$`) or other languages and like that, and you want to be fancy, you can indeed use a lot of things!

For instance, `$` works as an extension in many compilers:

```
int $() {
    return 42;
}
```

You can also use other Unicode characters:

```
int ᚁᚂᚃ() {
    return 42;
}
```

And, you can even use emoji:

```
int () {
    return 42;
}
```

See e.g. [Does C++11 allow dollar signs in identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301737/does-c11-allow-dollar-signs-in-identifiers) for more formal details.

Also, note that under MSVC you will probably want `/utf-8` and `/permissive-` if you want to play with this.

Comment: it's worth noting that not all toolchains fully support these identifiers in some cases. I know at least one linker that would probably barf on emoji

Comment: @Mgetz I can imagine... :)

Comment: i only found the list at the bottom here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers It has some really weird symbols and now I am a bit confused on what is really allowed and what not

Comment: indeed very fancy :) but it was mean to be used in macros, I edited my question

Comment: @Acorn just tested on godbolt: GCC: emoji rejected, MSVC: compiles, Clang: Compiles, ICC: Compiles

Comment: Your link led me to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494262/what-are-the-and-for-in-c-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 which says that those characters are basically not portable. Thanks, I have my answer

Comment: @Mgetz GCC should compile it, it is a bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224 (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g )