# Bool type True and False

Tags: c++, boolean, visual-c++

I was playing around with the Bool type (Boolean Variable) and typed this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

bool $ok = false & true;

if($ok == true)
{
    cout << "The value is True." << endl;
}
else if($ok == false)
{
    cout << "The value is false." << endl;
}

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

I know the differences between using the bitwise operator `&` and the logical operator `&&`, but I do not see how this produces a false (0) value. I know if I swapped the bitwise operator and used a `+` the expression `0+1` would cause it to evaluate to `true`. Can someone explain why this:

```
bool $ok = false & true;
```

evaluates to false?

Comment: Why did you expect it to be true?

Comment: I could be way off here, but wouldn't using the bitwise operator '&' with both the false and true predefined literals (0 ,1) that it would produce a true value? I don't know how/why it would or wouldn't, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Do you know how to compute a bitwise and? If not, [here's a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). Short answer, no.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know too much about it, I just know the differences between '&&' and '&' is all. I'm self taught and could use as many resources to learn as possible.

Comment: BTW do not use `$` in variable names in C++ if you want the code to be portable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

false=0(0x00000000)
true=1(0x00000001)

Now when we do bitwise and operator of (false & true)---(0&1=0).

```
            0x00000000
         &  0x00000001
          -------------
           0x00000000
```

Hence the result is 0(0x00000000)

Answer (score 1):

Why would this be true? `false` converts to a 0-valued integer. `true` converts to a non-zero valued integer (normally 1, but this is not guaranteed). `0 & x` for any `x` is always `0`. `0 == false` by definition of the integer/boolean interactions, thus the false branch is entered.

---

For what it's worth, over a domain of 0 and 1, with 0 as false and 1 as true, `*` maps to `AND` whereas `+` maps to `OR`. Given this, I'm not quite sure why you'd expect `+` and `&` to give the sameresults.

```
x * y != 0 iff x != 0 and y != 0
x + y != 0 iff x != 0 or y != 0
```

---

It's also worth mentioning that bit-wise operations on signed types tend to be a bad idea. If you're going to treat integers as bitfields, use unsigned integral types where the rules around the operations are much more natural and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `false` is 0 (when converted from boolean-land to integer-land), while `true` is 1 (when converted from boolean-land to integer-land).

```
false & true == 0 & 1 == 0 == false
false + true == 0 + 1 == 1 == true
```

If the magic of `&` is a mystery to you, [there are lots of great resources on bitwise-and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).