# Do the 'at' symbol (@) and dollar sign ($) have a special meaning in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, special-characters

Recently, one of my friends encountered this question in an interview. The interviewer asked him if the special characters like `$, @, |, ^, ~` have any usage in C or C++ and where.

I know that `|, ^ and ~` are used as *bitwise* OR, XOR and *complement* respectively.

Do `@` and `$` have any special meaning? If they do, what would be an example where it could be applied?

Comment: No, neither is part of the basic source character set, nor the basic execution character set.

Comment: @Arman For some definition of "special meaning".  They're illegal outside of comments, string literals and character literals.

Comment: @Arman My point was more or less that "special meaning" doesn't really mean anything.  The standard places a number of requirements on the meanings of a number of characters.  (FWIW: an implementation isn't required to accept $ or @ even in a comment or a string literal.  I dare any implementation not to, however.)

Comment: Note that Microsoft uses @ in library function names, followed by a number representing the number of bytes used for input parameters for certain 32 bit calling conventions, but these "mangled" names are only visible from assembly code, not from C or C++ code.

Comment: A canonical question is *[Dollar sign in variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/)* (2011).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`@` is generally invalid in C; it is not used for anything. It is used for various purposes by Objective-C, but that's a whole other kettle of fish.

`$` is invalid as well, but many implementations allow it to appear in identifiers, just like a letter. (In these implementations, for instance, you could name a variable or function `$$$` if you liked.) Even there, though, it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: Of course if an implementation decides not to support that, then your code suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: Aren't the only valid characters for names a-zA-z_0-9 ?

Comment: Corrected on `$`; forgot that was an extension.

Comment: @self., Or a *universal-character-name* (`\u` and `\U`), or other implementation-defined characters (`$` for example).

Comment: C++11 allows a-z A-Z 0-9 and underscore and *"other implementation-defined characters"*. So it is up to an implementation whether $ or another identifier is allowed. MSVC allows $. I'm not sure about other compilers.

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I remember GCC supporting it when I tried making a small, hackish, PHP-C++ thingy

Comment: @MattCoubrough: GCC and clang allow `$` as well. Between that and MSVC, that's the majority of the "big" compilers.

Comment: @MattCoubrough et al [GCC allows it too](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html)

Comment: Note that neither @ nor $ are valid for operator overloading either although you might be able to do evil things with preprocessor macros somehow

Comment: void $$$$ (void)
{
    printf ("Hai");
}
main()
{
    $$$$();

}
Error: suffix or operands invalid for `call'. How ?

Comment: @self it's allowed as extensions in gcc and MSVC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name

Comment: @mahendiran.b - It depends on the implementation. The code worked for me on gcc by adding int before main.#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
void $$$$ (void) { printf ("Hai"); }

int main()
{
   $$$$();
    return 0;
}

Comment: @MattCoubrough, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3346f35f86802704. Actually, that reminds me a lot of [this](http://i.imgur.com/r75gOVP.png), where I wrote [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75344cd23f7ad758). Now to go retrieve my nice Clang command line again because Clang didn't seem to like the dollar signs.

Comment: I also imagine it might be possible to do raw string literals with just `@(literal)` to make it look a bit more like C#.

Comment: MSVC, in particular, uses `$` and `@` in the names of certain hidden entities, like vtables.  For any class `C`, if it has a virtual function it'll have vtable `C::$vftable@`, and/or if it has a virtual base class it'll have vtable `C::$vbtable@`.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. It ought to be more comprehensive. At least it should be qualified, e.g., *"within the standard"* or similar.

Comment: From *[Dollar sign in variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/dollar-sign-in-variable-name/7926469#7926469)* (my emphasis): *"The only legal characters* ***according to the standard*** *are alphanumerics and the underscore. The standard does require that just about anything Unicode considers alphabetic is acceptable (but only as single code-point characters). In practice, implementations offer extensions (i.e. some do accept a $) and restrictions (most don't accept all of the required Unicode characters). "*

Answer (score 20):

To complete the accepted answer, the `@` can be used to specify the absolute address of a variable on embedded systems.

```
unsigned char buf[128]@0x2000;
```

Note this is a non-standard compiler extension.

Check out a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324663/5405361)

Comment: Why? Since C doesn't do compile-time bounds checking anyway (even when it can), what's the advantage over unsigned char *buf = 0x2000;?

Comment: @Muzer it makes a difference at least for `sizeof`. And then depending on your compiler and the flags used, you can have compile-time or runtime bounds checking.

Answer (score 12):

To complete the other answers. The C99-Standard in 5.2.1.3:

> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have
>   the following members:
>
> the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> `A B C D E F G H I J K L M` 
>   `N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`
>
> the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> `a b c d e f g h i j k l m` 
>   `n o p q r s t u v w x y z`
>
> the 10 decimal digits
>
> `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> `! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :`
>   `; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~`

All other characters maybe not even exist. (And should not be used)

But there is also this point in the Common extensions: Annex J, J.5.2:

> Characters other than the underscore _, letters, and digits, that are not part of the basic
>   source character set (such as the dollar sign $, or characters in national character sets)
>   may appear in an identifier (6.4.2).

Which is basically what duskwuff already wrote.