# Using @ in a C or C++ application

Tags: c++, c, validation, correctness, security-by-obscurity

I came to this obscure thing ... I would like to know if there are any possibilities for the **@** sign to appear in the source of a valid C/C++ application, beside of the following situations:

- a `const char*` value such as `const char* addr = "xyz@gmail.com"`
- a `const char` value, such as `char c = '@'`
- a macro which is never used: `#define NEVER_EVER ABC@`
- in a commented out section

Reason for asking: curiosity :)

Comment: `in a commented out section` pretty much anything can be there. :-)

Comment: There should possibly be separate questions for C and C++, the syntaxes are quite different. I can say that for C, there is no situation where an @ would be valid syntax and it is not an allowed char in tokens either. But I dont know about c++

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114365/does-at-symbol-and-dollar-sign-has-any-special-meaning-in-c-or-c).

Comment: I just tried `gcc -fextended-identifiers` and it still told me that `@` was a stray....

Comment: No unless it is some sort of extension (like that Objective-C that technically is extension to C or C++).

Comment: I think you've pretty much covered al the cases. The first two cases are trivially true. Just about any visible character is valid between double quotes (string) or as a single character between single quotes, as long as escaping rules are followed as needed. And as @SouravGhosh said, of course you can put anything in a comment. You can even put in control characters (a favorite way to do form feeds in a printed listing, back when folks did that, was to have a comment `/* ^L */`).

Comment: Why is this tagged security-by-obscurity?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo An educated guess would be that OP wants to use `@` to obfuscate his code.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein you're getting close :) Indeed, I'm researching various obscure ways to obfuscate my code

Comment: Perhaps interesting: I thought another exception might be the delimiter in C++11's raw string literals, but it's not allowed even there. An obvious addition to your rules is a macro which *is* used, but where the expansion is stringized.

Answer (score 3):

I would answer for the C language. Note that there isn't any such thing as C/C++. Both are separate languages and C is *not* a subset of C++.

Beside those possibilities, that you described, `@` can be also placed in header names, but it's not a common practice:

#### `main.c:`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "fancy@header.h"

int main(void)
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

#### `fancy@header.h:`

```
static void foo(void)
{
    printf("whatever\n");
}
```

For a *Standard* reference to cover this, you might look into [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) §5.2.1/p3 that covers the *basic execution character set*, which does not include the `@` character. This paragraph also provides a list of cases that may allow a `@` character (emphasis mine):

> In the basic execution character set, there shall be control
> characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new
> line. If **any other characters** are encountered in a source file (except
> in an identifier, a character constant, a string literal, a **header
> name**, a comment, or a preprocessing token that is never converted to a
> token), the behavior is undefined.

In case of identifiers, see C11 §6.4.2.1/p3:

> Each universal character name in an identifier shall designate a
> character whose encoding in ISO/IEC 10646 falls into one of the ranges
> specified in D.1.<sup>71)</sup> The initial character shall not be a universal
> character name designating a character whose encoding falls into one
> of the ranges specified in D.2. An implementation may allow multibyte
> characters that are not part of the basic source character set to
> appear in identifiers; which characters and their correspondence to
> universal character names is implementation-defined.

The D.1 (normative) appendix section lists ranges of allowed characters. As you might check the `@` character can be represented as `U+0040` in [UCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set), that is outside of allowed range:

> 00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2−00B5, 00B7−00BA, 00BC−00BE, 00C0−00D6,
> 00D8−00F6, 00F8−00FF (...)

Even with that, compiler might allow `@` character as *language extension*. C11 J.5.2/p1 *Specialized identifiers* *(Common extensions)* contains:

> Characters other than the underscore _, letters, and digits, that are
> not part of the basic source character set (such as the dollar sign $,
> or characters in national character sets) may appear in an **identifier**
> (6.4.2).

For instance GCC allows `$` sign as [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs) in that way:

> In GNU C, you may normally use dollar signs in identifier names. This
> is because many traditional C implementations allow such identifiers.
> However, dollar signs in identifiers are not supported on a few target
> machines, typically because the target assembler does not allow them.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem with all the above.

The @ is invalid in names (variables, functions, classes, etc.)
Some linkers actually use the @ character as "at" meaning to relate symbols to libraries. (try to `nm` some of your executables in Linux);
you'll see something like this: `malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5` means `malloc` taken from GLIBC_2.2.5.

In strings and characters, the only problematic seen character is the `\` which is also used as an escape character and the `"` in strings and `'` in characters which must be escaped to not be translated as end of string/character.

In comments, there aren't any limitations except the `*/` in multi-line comment which will close the comment.

A never-used macro does not really exist after precompilation, so there isn't any problem at all.

Comment: '@' is **not** part of the required *basic source character set*, so it could cause problems in a conforming implementation. (N4296 2.3 [lex.charset] p1)

Comment: The other two "aliens" out of the set of printable ASCII-7 characters that are not part of the *basic source character set* are the dollar sign `$` and the backtick.