# Use of the @ symbol in C programming

Tags: c

I'm working with some code that was originally written for [IAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAR_Systems#IAR_Embedded_Workbench) and converting it to compile using the GCC compiler.

However, I'm stuck with one particular line as I don't understand the syntax or what is going on.

```
__root const uint32_t part_number @ ".part_number" = 701052;
```

The __root I've found out is so that the the variable is included in the final code even if there is nothing that actually references it.  *const* means that it won't change and is kept in the ROM instead of RAM.

It is the @ ".part_number" part that I don't follow. The specific error I get is "stray '@' in program".

I understand that @ isn't a part of standard C, but I haven't had any luck finding anything that explains this syntax I'm seeing.

Comment: I suspect that it's an instruction  for the linker to place that variable in the correspondingly named executable section. The gcc equivalent would be the `section` attribute (`const uint32_t part_number __attribute__ ((section (".part_number")) = 701052;`).

Comment: Not committing a full answer since I'm not certain, but the ".part_number" tells me it's probably telling the linker which section to store the variable/value in

Comment: Try out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114365/does-at-symbol-and-dollar-sign-has-any-special-meaning-in-c-or-c). The 3rd answer suggests that it's a non-standard compiler extension for specifying a physical address

Comment: I agree with Matteo and Frank's comments.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  Really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this KB entry](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/compiler/linker-error-for-absolute-located-variable/), it looks like it's syntax to instruct the linker to place the variable into a specific section:

> If you instead place the object into a named segment:
>
> ```
> __no_init struct setup located_configuration @ "SETUP";
> ```

The equivalent GCC syntax is through the `section` attribute.

```
const uint32_t part_number __attribute__ ((section (".part_number")) = 701052;
```