# C++ code is wrong

Tags: c++

I was coding in PHP for few weeks, but now I want to learn C++.

This is my code:

```
$variable = 16;
std::cout << variable;
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `$variable` is an illegal name for a variable in c++ see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name plus it has no type such as `int`, `double` etc.

Comment: Do not just guess how C++ might work, you will fail horribly. Read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ systematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use google.
2. In C++ you must define a type of variable.
3. Look for a C++ tutorial, there are many of them.
4. Use google.

Comment: 5. get a [decent book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). 6. read it. (Actually these should be 1. and 2.)