# Can we use currency signs in variable declaration in C++ language?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

Can we use the currency signs like `₹` and `$` while declaring variable in C++ language?
I tried to find the answer on google but I was not clear about it.We can not use special symbols like `#`,`*`,`%` in variable names in c++ language but can we use currency signs like `₹` and `$` as variable names?

Comment: No, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers)

Comment: [Yes](https://godbolt.org/z/f341KhY1q), but it requires compiler support, and it is not standard C++.

Comment: Not in standard C++.    That said, some compilers do provide non-standard extensions.   But most compilers do not provide such extensions.

Comment: *"Can we use currency signs in variable declaration..."* Don't just don't. It will only lead to non-portable code. See [Dollar sign in variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/dollar-sign-in-variable-name)

Answer (score 0):

You sort of can if you use "user defined literals".
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal
However not all compilers will be happy with the rupee special character (MSVC accepts it)
Example here :

```
#include <iostream>

struct dollars_t
{
    double value;
};

struct rupees_t
{
    double value;
};

constexpr dollars_t operator "" _$(long double value)
{
    return dollars_t{ static_cast<double>(value) };
};

constexpr rupees_t operator "" _₹(long double value)
{
    return rupees_t{ static_cast<double>(value) };
};


int main()
{
    auto dollars = 10.12_$;
    auto rupees = 1000.12_₹;

    std::cout << "You have " << dollars.value << " dollars\n";
    std::cout << "And you have " << rupees.value << " rupees\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think op is asking to use special characters in variable names, eg `int ₹ = 0;`

Comment: Hehe yeah something I tend to overthink things. O well

Comment: nice answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70435254/4117728) ;)

Comment: Thanks I'll post it there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use currency signs in variable names such as

```
int dollar_$;
int inr_₹;
```