# How to use dollar / euro sign in code to initialize a variable?

Tags: c++, currency

I want to write some code that uses different types of currencies, eg

```
struct euro {
    int value;
};

struct dollar {
    int value;
};
```

Now I'd like to use the euro and dollars sign in code, something like

```
euro e = 3€;
dollar d = 3$;
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Why have two different structures for the same kind of data? Why not store the amount (`value`) and the currency (Euro or Dollar) in a single structure?

Comment: As for your problem you might want to read about [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). Not sure if the Euro or Dollar symbols are valid though. Perhaps `3_euro` and `6_dollar` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because I want to overload functions based on the type of currency

Comment: Whereas `$` is in ascii range, `€` is not, so it would be more problematic...

Comment: Won't something like this work? `void someFunc( dollar&& amount );` and then `someFunc( dollar(3) );`

Comment: @Jarod42 I think it's the other way around, actually -- as a "regular" Unicode symbol, the Euro symbol is accepted as a standard universal character, but the dollar symbol is not.

Comment: U+20AC "Euro" is a valid identifier character.  U+0024 "Dollar Sign" is not a valid identifier character.  U+1F4B2 "Heavy Dollar Sign" is a valid identifier character.

Comment: @Eljay actually most compilers accept `$` as a valid character in identifiers as an extension: [dollar sign in variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7926394/995714). But not all compilers deal well with Unicode characters in identifiers

Comment: @phuclv • All the C++ compilers I use either accept `$` as an identifier character, or if a compiler flag is provided will accept `$`.  (And, I admit, I use `$` in some of my identifiers, in particular `FOO$` is a macro, and `$BAR(x)` is a function-like macro.  I only use `$` in macros.  I hate macros.)  But it's not standard C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [user defined lietrals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). The code below worked for me using `g++ 11.1.0` but I guess that there could be some problems with non ASCII €. Maybe try using `EUR` suffix? For negative values see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430296/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-literal-for-a-signed-integer-type).

```
#include <charconv>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
    
struct euro
{
    unsigned long long val;
};

euro operator"" _€ (unsigned long long num)
{
    return euro {num};
}

int main()
{
    euro e = 123_€;
    std::cout << e.val << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Don't do the ull thing. Its a short term optimization it will be confusing later (or to other people). Be as explicit as you can and only use aliases to really represent a concept, not for saving some type work.

Comment: You could replace `unsigned long long int` with `uint64_t`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks, I've removed the alias.

Answer (score 3):

You can get close to this syntax with user defined literals :
Note not all compilers accept special characters but my MSVC does.
Ofcourse you could make one currency class and do some kind of conversion  based on exchange rates but that's up to you :)

```
#include <iostream>

struct dollars_t
{
    double value;
};

struct rupees_t
{
    double value;
};

constexpr dollars_t operator "" _$(long double value)
{
    return dollars_t{ static_cast<double>(value) };
};

constexpr rupees_t operator "" _₹(long double value)
{
    return rupees_t{ static_cast<double>(value) };
};


int main()
{
    auto dollars = 10.12_$;
    auto rupees = 1000.12_₹;

    std::cout << "You have " << dollars.value << " dollars\n";
    std::cout << "And you have " << rupees.value << " rupees\n";

    return 0;
}
```