# Double Dollar sign in C Program

Tags: c, gcc

I found in some Arm reference software, in the file, "arch/arm/armv7-m/src/arch_exceptions.c," the following lines:

```
#ifdef __ARMCC_VERSION 
extern char Image$$ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP$$ZI$$Limit;
           
#    define arch_exception_stack (&Image$$ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP$$ZI$$Limit)
#else
extern char __stackheap_end__;

#    define arch_exception_stack (&__stackheap_end__)
#endif
```

I know `##` is used for string concatenation but I've never seen this double `$$` sign. Not knowing what that is, I can't search for the right term.

How is this `$$` used in C?

Comment: `gcc` allows unicode in variable names

Comment: The compiler probably allows dollar signs in identifiers as an extension to play nicer with the platform's conventions.

Comment: Most (if not all)  modern compilers allow the `$` sign in identifiers.

Comment: Yeah, it looks so. I found in some other files in an inline assemble `LDR    SP, =Image$$FIQ_STACK$$ZI$$Limit`. So it looks like just a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dollar sign in variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/dollar-sign-in-variable-name)

Comment: @DavidRanieri this has nothing to do with Unicode identifier. Most compilers have supported dollar symbol in identifiers as an extension for decades

Comment: @phuclv I did not say otherwise and question is tagged `gcc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not those `$$` 'field-separators' have any specific meaning to the target assembler and/or linker, I can't say, but the GNU C compiler does allow [dollar signs in identifier names](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html).

So, presumably, `Image$$ARM_LIB_STACKHEAP$$ZI$$Limit` is the name of an `extern char` variable defined in one of the support libraries for the Arm platform.